# What does super refer to in a private nested class that doesn't extend any other classes?

Tags: java

I have a class with a nested inner class like so

```
class Outer {
    private class Inner {
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use IntelliJ to override `hashcode()` within the Inner class, IntelliJ generates the above function. But what does `super` here refer to exactly? My Inner class doesn't inherit from any other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All classes extends `java.lang.Object` (except `java.lang.Object`).

It will be the `hashCode` method of the `Inner` instance, not `Outer`.